# перестает работать ссылка(css)

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

Есть блок, вот его код [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема: блок-ссылка и ведет на страницу, но на блок с помощью css добавлен эффект hover, при котором возможность кликнуть по ссылке пропадает, вот css код:

```css
.service-thumbnail{
  display:block;
  width:230px;
  height:230px;  
  border:7px solid #fff;
  box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px gray;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:linear-gradient(145deg,#4a35c5,#ba13c5);
  position:relative;
  color:transparent;
  transition:all .5s ease;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
.service-thumbnail:after{
  content:'\f0c1';
  font-family:fontAwesome;
  font-size:40px;
  line-height:1;
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - .5em);
  left:calc(50% - .5em);
 z-index: 2;
}
.service-thumbnail img{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:inherit;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position:center;
  transition:inherit;
}
.service-thumbnail:hover{
  color:#fff;
}
.service-thumbnail:hover img{
  opacity:.4;
}
```

Comment: Код надо выкладывать текстом, а не картинкой. Он должен индексироваться.

Comment: Уже предоставил решение проблемы.

Comment: @Zicrael неважно. Код все равно надо выложить текстом.

Comment: Полностью согласен с вами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все верно, вы перекрываете ссылку hover блоком, вам нужно ссылку вставить в hover блок. Вот рабочий пример:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.hoverEffect {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: opacity  1s ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 6px;
  background-color:  rgba(128,0,128, 0.6);

}

.wrapper img {
  border: 1px solid #a0522d;
  padding: 5px;
}
.wrapper , .wrapper img , .hoverEffect {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
}

.wrapper:hover .hoverEffect {
  opacity: 1;
}
.hoverEffect a { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <img src="https://i2.wp.com/beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg?resize=640%2C426" alt="image">
    <div class='hoverEffect'>
        <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/y2y4kdm8/">
             <i class="fas fa-link"></i>
         </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/y2y4kdm8/3/) на JSFiddle

Comment: А если нет возможности редактировать html код, есть какое-то разрешение проблемы?

Comment: Выход есть всегда: D. `.hoverEffect { pointer-events: none; }`.  Отпишетесь о результате:)

Comment: Что-то я пытаюсь, но не выходит. А по моему коду , какому селектору я должен присвоить?

Comment: Тому селектору который отвечает за блок поверх картинки при hover.